# z-index reversed in iOS and Safari macOS

Tags: ios, css, macos, safari, z-index

The z-index of these images is set so they should be staked blue, red, green but in iOS browsers and Safari on macOS the order is reversed so they display green, red, blue.

Here is a CodePen, the issue effects all iOS browsers and Safari on macOS.

https://codepen.io/W3-design/pen/pBOJyy

HTML:

```
<div class="stacked-images">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/0000FF">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/FF0000">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/00FF00">
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.stacked-images {
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;

    img {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.9;
      transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
      transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-55deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,-30deg);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-55deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,-30deg);

      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        z-index: 90;
        top: 80px;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        z-index: 80;
        top: 160px;
      }

      &:hover {
          transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0) scale(1.1,1.1);
          -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0) scale(1.1,1.1);
          opacity: 1;
          z-index: 101;
      }
   }
}
```

I would like the z-index to be the same across all browsers.

Comment: @Paulw11, where do you get this from? All references I've read use "-webkit-transform:" even if I take the "-webkit-transform:" line out it makes no difference.

Comment: Hmm.  I was messing around with your CodePen and got it working correctly.  I thought that was the change I made that did the trick, but it isn't working now...

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, would be great if you could repeat your changes, it's just an aesthetic thing but it's bugging me :)

Comment: I found a few semi-duplicates here on SO.  It isn't that the order is reversed as such, I think it is just that Safari is ignoring the z-index

Comment: I've read a few of those safari z-index questions but none of the solutions seem to work for my example.

Comment: No, I can't get them to work either. The underlying cause seems to be the same; applying a 3D transformation breaks the z ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```css
.stacked-images {
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 55deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -30deg);
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 90;
  top: 80px;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  z-index: 80;
  top: 160px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0) scale(1.1, 1.1);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<div class="stacked-images">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/0000FF">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/FF0000">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180/00FF00">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kosh, would you mind explaining why this works, I must be missing something as the SCSS I have should result in similar code to the CSS you provided apart from the nested classes.